# Display object by its property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am still learning Javascript, and I have data and trying to to display by its category. I'm confused which method to use to achieved that. Here is my object

```
const data = [
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shoes",
     price: 599,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "phones",
     price: 898,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shirt",
     price: 788,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "ball",
     price: 455,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "laptop",
     price: 999,
  },
  {
     category: "beauty",
     items: "lipstick",
     price: 888,
  },
];
```

The result that I want is more or less like the code snippet below. And thank for your help. I hope you guys understand, because my English is not good enough. **Edited**, the data is dynamic from users input

```css
div{
  display: flex
}

section{
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>electronics</h1>
  <div>
    <p>phones</p>
    <p>898</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>laptop</p>
    <p>999</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>sports</h1>
  <div>
    <p>shoes</p>
    <p>599</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>shirt</p>
    <p>788</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>ball</p>
    <p>455</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>beauty</h1>
  <div>
    <p>lipstick</p>
    <p>888</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how you could create a new array with the values you wanted using `array.filter()`

```js
const data = [
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shoes",
     price: 599,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "phones",
     price: 898,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shirt",
     price: 788,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "ball",
     price: 455,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "laptop",
     price: 999,
  },
  {
     category: "beauty",
     items: "lipstick",
     price: 888,
  },
];
function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( a.category < b.category ){
    return 1;
  }
  if ( a.category > b.category ){
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(data.sort( compare ));
```

Here i am filtering by every category and then pushing it to a new array in order to get the result i want.

Comment: But, the data are dynamic. It's from user input. I dont know how much categories will available

Comment: @Tom-Cat i updated the answer. Now you compare each category and sort them like that.You can create your won compare function in order to get the result you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Basically the idea is to transform you array into an object  of this form

```
{
  "category1": [{}, {}] //item with category1,
  "category2": [{}, {}] //item with category2,
}
```

the syntax

```
return {
   ...res,
   [item.category]: [...(res[item.category] || []), item]
  }
```

means that it return all previously category in the object (...res)

for the current category it takes all the items in that category (res[item.category]) or empty array if is not defined and set a new array with the previous values plus the current one

```js
const data = [
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shoes",
     price: 599,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "phones",
     price: 898,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "shirt",
     price: 788,
  },
  {
     category: "sports",
     items: "ball",
     price: 455,
  },
  {
     category: "electronics",
     items: "laptop",
     price: 999,
  },
  {
     category: "beauty",
     items: "lipstick",
     price: 888,
  },
];

//first group by category
const grouppedByCategory = data.reduce((res, item) => {
  
  return {
   ...res,
   [item.category]: [...(res[item.category] || []), item]
  }

}, {})


//then transform your groupped elements into html
const html = Object.entries(grouppedByCategory).map(([cat, products]) => `<section>
  <h1>${cat}</h1>
  ${products.map(({price, items}) => `<div>
    <p>${items}</p>
    <p>${price}</p>
  </div>`).join('') }
</section>`).join('')

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html
```

```css
div{
  display: flex
}

section{
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<main id="container"></main>
```

Comment: can you explain about the return in reduce ?

Comment: @Tom-Cat I edited my answer with some explanation. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Make an object of categories with the value of an array consisting of an object made of the name & price of the product,
And at the end just loop through the keys of the object and do the DOM manipulations,

```
const data = [
  {
    category: "sports",
    items: "shoes",
    price: 599,
  },
  {
    category: "electronics",
    items: "phones",
    price: 898,
  },
];

const categorys = {};
data.forEach((product) => {
  let category = product.category;
  if (!categorys[category]) categorys[category] = [];
  categorys[category].push(product);
});

for (category in categorys) {
  console.log(categorys[category]);
  //do dom manipulation here,
  //the best thing to do would be to create the element
  //and update the dom just once after the loop ends
}
```

Comment: can you explaine 'if (!categorys[category]) categorys[category] = [];
  categorys[category].push(product);' ?

Comment: ! this is called a bang operator, it can be used to check if a variable has a falsy value,
in this case, if `categorys[category]` does not exist, it will return true, and I suppose the rest of the code is pretty self-explanatory,
and if you are confused about `obj[key]` , it is used to access a property using a string stored within some variable as the key

Answer (score 1):

1. Group the data by its category using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
2. And then loop over all the categories and for every category loop over all the items and create the desired markup.

```js
const data = [
  { category: "sports", item: "shoes", price: 599 },
  { category: "electronics", item: "phones", price: 898 },
  { category: "sports", item: "shirt", price: 788 },
  { category: "sports", item: "ball", price: 455 },
  { category: "electronics", item: "laptop", price: 999 },
  { category: "beauty", item: "lipstick", price: 888 },
];

const categories = data.reduce(
  (r, o) => ((r[o.category] ??= []).push(o), r),
  {}
);

Object.keys(categories).forEach((cat) => {
  const section = document.createElement("section");
  const heading = document.createElement("h2");
  heading.textContent = cat;
  section.appendChild(heading);

  categories[cat].forEach((item) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const itemPara = document.createElement("p");
    itemPara.textContent = item.item;
    const pricePara = document.createElement("p");
    pricePara.textContent = item.price;
    div.appendChild(itemPara);
    div.appendChild(pricePara);
    section.appendChild(div);
  });

  document.body.appendChild(section);
});
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

section h2 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

section div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section div p {
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
}
```

**Relevant documentations:**

- [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm an old-fashioned guy who loves tables...

```js
const data = [{
    category: "sports",
    items: "shoes",
    price: 599,
  },
  {
    category: "electronics",
    items: "phones",
    price: 898,
  },
  {
    category: "sports",
    items: "shirt",
    price: 788,
  },
  {
    category: "sports",
    items: "ball",
    price: 455,
  },
  {
    category: "electronics",
    items: "laptop",
    price: 999,
  },
  {
    category: "beauty",
    items: "lipstick",
    price: 888,
  },
];

// group data by category
const grouped = data
  .reduce((c, { category, ...rest }) => {
    c[category] = c[category] || [];
    c[category].push({ ...rest });
    return c;
  }, {})

// write it to the table
// create the header
const thead = document.getElementById('header');
let row = document.createElement('tr');
Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(k => {
  let hdr = document.createElement('th');
  hdr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k));
  row.appendChild(hdr);
});
thead.appendChild(row);

// now fill the body
const tbody = document.getElementById('products');
for (const [category, products] of Object.entries(grouped)) {
  let row = document.createElement('tr');
  let cat = document.createElement('td');
  cat.setAttribute('rowSpan', products.length);
  cat.appendChild(document.createTextNode(category));
  row.appendChild(cat);
  products.forEach(product => {
    Object.values(product).forEach(v => {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    row = document.createElement('tr');
  });
}
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead id="header"></thead>
  <tbody id="products">
  </tbody>
</table>
```